# Битые пакеты в Game Center (UPD: проблема с битностью 32/64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, сервер

Реализовал мультиплеер в игре по [туториалу мультиплеера Game Center](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60998/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-2), но столкнулся с проблемой, на разных устройствах это работает по разному, если быть точнее, то  определенные устройства отправляют битые пакеты информации.

**Получается следующее:**

**1 ситуация:** есть два устройства, они конектятся между собой и все работает нормально, оба отправляют и получают корректные пакеты с информацией

**2 ситуация:** есть два устройства, они конектятся между собой, но одно устройство получает корректные пакеты с информацией, а второе устройство битые пакеты

При этом проблема не конкретно в моей реализации, можно скачать тестовый проект по ссылки из туториала выше, и там все работает точно так же.

Работа данного кода была проверена на 7 устройствах, на 5-х все работает как надо: `iPhone 6 (iOS10), iPhone 5S (iOS9), iPad Mini 2 (iOS11), iPhone 6S+ (iOS10), iPhone 5S (iOS10)` - при этом конектились они между собой в разных комбинациях, все работает. 
На двух устройствах данный код не работает: `iPad 4 (iOS9), iPhone 5 (iOS10)` - эти устройства получают корректные пакеты данных, но второе устройство от них получает битые пакеты.

Тестировалось на разных интернет соединения, так что дело не в сети, а конкретно в составлении и отправки/получения пакета.

Может кто подсказать в чем может быть проблема, возможно кто сталкивался с этим? Пример проекта можно скачать по ссылке выше из туторила, там эта проблема тоже есть.

**UPD:** Получается скорее всего косяк в битности процессора.. если сконектить iPad 4 (32 бита) и iPhone 5 (32 бита) то все будет работать как надо, но стоит их сконектить с любым 64 битным процессором, то начинаются проблемы, 64 битный получает битые данные от 32 битного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Нашел такой же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078220/sending-nsdata-from-32bit-to-64bit-in-multiplayer-game-using-game-centre-in-ios), но там не отвечают на то как решить данную проблему, использовать `uint32_t` не вариант, ибо сам `typedef struct` приходит в другой битности. Но вариант перейти на `json` более менее подходит.